# grails loginfilter blocks css

Tags: grails, grails-filters

I've some troubles with my loginfilter in grails. If there is no session, it redirects me to the login page, but it blocks the css.

```
class LoginFilters {
def filters = {
    loginCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        before = {
            println("USER: "+session.user)
            println("ActionName: "+actionName)
            println("Controller: "+controllerName)

            if (session.user == null) {             
                println("Redirecting to Loginpage")
                render(view: '/index');
                return true

            }else{
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Where is my problem?

Comment: your code `render` index page, not `redirect` to

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, you should post that as an answer :)

Comment: I think it's too short to be answer :)